# IOS: NSpredicate with array and search bar

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I am new to IOS programming and i want your help.
First of all, i have  a table view which contains the objects of an `NSMutablearray` "recs".
I have inserted a `UISearchBar`, with purpose to find the each object from recs i want..
When i try to key in the searchbar, it crashes and the following message appears to log files

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use in/contains operator with collection <Person: 0x8e20b10> (not a collection)'
```

I show you  a part of my code which contains the NSPredicate:

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
// Tells the table data source to reload when text changes
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
 [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
// Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
return YES;
```

}

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
// Update the filtered array based on the search text and scope.
// Remove all objects from the filtered search array
[self.searcharray removeAllObjects];
// Filter the array using NSPredicate
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self contains[cd] %@",searchText];
_searcharray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[_recs filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

}

I am very confused...
Please help me!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that your array contains `Person` objects and not just
strings. In that case you have to specify a *property* of the `Person` class that should be used for searching, for example:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastName CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];
```